# How to load static css into django template

Tags: python, django

I'm just newbie in django. Just learning. Want to know how to make best loading of css into django template. Work in `django-env` with django 1.8

So, how I'm trying
settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('static', '/home/djangoenv/bin/mysuperapp/static'),
)
```

my_template

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "/css/foundation.css" %}'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Django</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

In this case I have no loaded css and a warning message in Chrome Console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/foundation.css".
```

Comment: Just add a base static dir to your STATICFILES_DIRS setting, then let the app static loader take care of app specific static folders. Kinda like; `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static'),)`

Comment: @marksweb, There is no effect. =(

Answer (score 3):

Remove `'static'` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/djangoenv/bin/mysuperapp/static',
)
```

This `static` creates separate namespace, so you would have to call `{% static "static/css/foundation.css" %}`.

And use `static` templatetag without leading slash: `{% static "css/foundation.css" %}`.

Comment: Yeap, I've already checked. But I still don't understand where is the fault.

Comment: I've tried. Now I get error "404". If use in template `{% static "/css/foundation.css" %}` have again the same warning.

Comment: Do you have ```DEBUG``` set to ```False``` in settings? If yes, you have to call ```python manage.py collectstatic```.

Comment: It say `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path`. What I should do?

Comment: Set ```STATIC_ROOT``` in settings. This is folder where Django collects static files. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT